# What is a convenient way to write OSM data to a .shp file in python

Tags: python, fiona, overpass-api

I wish grab OSM data that is within a specified bounding box and matches specific key/value combinations. I then want to write this to a .shp file for further processing using, probably, the QGIS api.

I have successfully acquired OSM data within the bounding box using [overpy](https://github.com/DinoTools/python-overpy) and have it within an overpy.Result object. I just can't find a way to write it to a .shp file?

Can anyone direct me to a suitable fragment, preferably one that uses [fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html)?

Comment: OSM data (as well as all WMS data) is in raster format, usually in the form of PNG tiles. If you're going to be grabbing these tiles, they can't be converted to .shp, as that extension is reserved for vector data. It is possible to export portions of an OSM map in QGIS Desktop, but it looks like you've already got that part covered. I may be misunderstanding what you wish to achieve though. Can you clarify your goal a bit?

Comment: No, OSM data follows an XML like syntax. 
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML

Comment: How about just downloading in shape file format from one of the available locations? http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Downloading

Comment: @shongololo, thanks but what I want to do is get (a series of) specific key/values within a bounding box on work on that specific subset. Those resources seem to offer the whole dataset or a large subset thereof. Am I missing something?

Comment: @lovelyzoo yes, they tend to offer bulk downloads by country, some offer them by city. Thus another option is to download the shapefile, open it with fiona, do any filtering based on bounding boxes etc. using shapely, then write to a new shapefile with fiona. Though I suppose you could also do much of the filtering directly in QGIS on the shapefile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I use the first example of [overpy](https://github.com/DinoTools/python-overpy)

```
import overpy
api = overpy.Overpass()
# fetch all ways and nodes
result = api.query("""
way(50.746,7.154,50.748,7.157) ["highway"];
(._;>;);
out body;
""")
```

The resulting script give the names and the nodes of the ways. which are actualy the nodes of a LineString:

```
for way in result.ways:
    print("Name: %s" % way.tags.get("name", "n/a"))
    print("  Highway: %s" % way.tags.get("highway", "n/a"))
    print("  Nodes:")
    for node in way.nodes:
        print("    Lat: %f, Lon: %f" % (node.lat, node.lon))
    Name: Rhedenstraße
    Highway: residential
    Nodes:
        Lat: 50.746874, Lon: 7.156307
        Lat: 50.746598, Lon: 7.156237
        Lat: 50.746477, Lon: 7.156199
        ....
```

Therefore with Fiona:

```
import fiona 
from fiona.crs import from_epsg
schema = {'geometry': 'LineString', 'properties': {'Name':'str:80'}}
shapeout = "test.shp"
with fiona.open(shapeout, 'w',crs=from_epsg(4326),driver='ESRI Shapefile', schema=schema) as output:
    for way in result.ways:
        # the shapefile geometry use (lon,lat) 
        line = {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates':[(node.lon, node.lat) for node in way.nodes]}
        prop = {'Name': way.tags.get("name", "n/a")}
        output.write({'geometry': line, 'properties':prop})
```

Control of the resulting shapefile

```
 c = fiona.open("test.shp")
 # first 
 c.next()
 {'geometry': {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': [(7.1563067, 50.7468739), (7.1562371, 50.7465981), (7.1561995, 50.746477), (7.1561245, 50.7463604), (7.1560233, 50.746263), (7.1559261, 50.7461938), (7.155843, 50.7461387)]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '0', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'name', u'Rhedenstra\xdfe')])}
```

Control with QGIS (in red):

[image]

You can add

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful and has largely answered my question. What is still mysterious to me is how you have determined the schema. What would help would be a document that can disentangle which concepts are native to OSM/Overpass and which are coming from the shapefile format. Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: I determine the schema simply looking at the attributes given by the tutorial script (Name and Highway)